# Two questions of c++ which just change a little,however very different answers

Tags: c++, gnu

Recently I do a exercise about algorithm with c++. Exercise in here:[poj](http://poj.org/problem?id=3083)

I find two very confused questions. 
 I write a class MAZE and there are three primary functions in MAZE,they are 
`int left_path();int right_path();int mini_path();` 
and a function to print the answers:

```
void display(){
    cout<<left_path()<<" "<<right_path()<<" ";
    cout<<mini_path()<<endl;
}
```

the program can work correctly.As we see the function display() can be easy;
I write like this

```
void display(){
    cout<<left_path()<<" "<<right_path()<<" "<<mini_path()<<endl;
}
```

just one change ;however the program can't work,it like loop infinitely.

following is the other question:
 the function mini_path's frame like this

```
int maze::mini_path(){
    ini();
    queue<pair<int,int> > q;
    q.push(make_pair(x,y));
    while(!q.empty()){

        pair<int,int> tmp=q.front();
       q.pop();

       int t=...;
       if(E){
          return t;
       }
       if(E){
        S
       }
       if(E){
         S
       }
       if(E){
          S
       }
       if(E){
          S
       } 

   }
    return -1;
}
```

if there is "return -1" in the end ,the function works right,else the function return random big number.

**The program is in only one file and i use the gun compiler.**

**I don't show the total codes,because i think nobody wants to see them.I just want to ask what problems may lead above strange  behaviors.**

source code(simplified for question2):

```
    typedef enum {LEFT=-1,RIGHT=1,UP,DOWN} direction;

    ifstream fin("file_test3.txt");
    class maze{
    public:
        maze(){input();}
        int mini_path();
        void input();
        void display(){
            cout<<mini_path()<<endl;
        }
    private:
        bool is_not_dest(){
            return !(x==d_x && y==d_y);
        }
        void ini_dir()
        {
            if(e_x==0) dir=DOWN;
            else if(e_x==height-1) dir=UP;
            else if(e_y==0) dir=RIGHT;
            else dir=LEFT;
        }
        void ini(){
            x=e_x;
            y=e_y;
            path_lenth=1;
            ini_dir();
        }
        direction dir,d;
        int width,height,maze_map[40][40],path_lenth;
        int x,y,e_x,e_y,d_x,d_y;
    };
    void maze::input()
{
    fin>>width>>height;
    char sym;
    for(int i=0;i<height;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<width;++j){
            fin>>sym;
            if(sym=='#')
                maze_map[i][j]=1;
            else if(sym=='.')
                maze_map[i][j]=0;
            else if(sym=='S'){
                maze_map[i][j]=-1;
                e_x=i;
                e_y=j;
            }
            else {
                maze_map[i][j]=-2;
                d_x=i;
                d_y=j;
            }
        }
}

int maze::mini_path()
{
    ini();
    queue<pair<int,int> > q;

    if(dir==LEFT) {maze_map[x][--y]=2;}
    else if(dir==RIGHT) {maze_map[x][++y]=2;}
    else if(dir==UP) {maze_map[--x][y]=2;}
    else {maze_map[++x][y]=2;}

    q.push(make_pair(x,y));
   while(!q.empty()){
        pair<int,int> tmp=q.front();
        q.pop();
        x=tmp.first;
        y=tmp.second;
        int t=maze_map[x][y]+1;
        if((x==d_x && (y-d_y==1 || y-d_y==-1)) ||(y==d_y && (x-d_x==1||x-d_x==-1))){
            return t;
        }
        if(maze_map[x-1][y]==0){
            maze_map[x-1][y]=t;
            q.push(make_pair(x-1,y));
        }
        if(maze_map[x+1][y]==0){
            maze_map[x+1][y]=t;
            q.push(make_pair(x+1,y));
        }
        if(maze_map[x][y-1]==0){
            maze_map[x][y-1]=t;
            q.push(make_pair(x,y-1));
        }
        if(maze_map[x][y+1]==0){
            maze_map[x][y+1]=t;
            q.push(make_pair(x,y+1));
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

main()
{
    int n;
    fin>>n;
    while(n-- >0){
        class maze m;
        m.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bugs in your code leads to the strange behavior. Since you didn't show us your code we can't tell you where the bugs are.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger. This may help you solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Using gun compiler, you are surprised to shoot yourself in foot? (Sorry for the sarkasm, but the quality of this question seems exceptionally low to me)

Comment: -1 vague and incomplete question.

Answer (score 5):

I see it! Can you see it? :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo(int bar)
{
    cout << bar << endl;
    return bar;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << foo(1) << foo(2) << foo(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
3
2
1
123
```

Comment: Yes, the undefined order of calls is what triggers his problem, it's not his *bug* though. At least as far as I can parse his question :)

Comment: @Erik - no, it's not. The bug is elsewhere in his code. But this should set him on the right track. Anyways, this is as much as can be answered given the information he has presented us with.

Comment: Thank you!I know the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

regarding question1:
The order in which the functions are called will be different.
the first solution will call them in following order:

1. right_path
2. left_path
3. mini_path

the second solution results in following order:

1. mini_path
2. right_path
3. left_path

so the solution you probaly want is:

```
void display(){
    cout<<left_path()<<" ";
    cout<<right_path()<<" ";
    cout<<mini_path()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The real solution is of course to **not** have updating functions in the output statements. First compute your values, then display them.

Answer (score -2):

There is not enough info to answer the first question; both codes are equivalent.

[Edit:Check other answers. Anyway, both codes *should be* equivalent: you have bugs in your code.]

About the second question, I guess that that "return -1" marks "no possible path" in your maze, that's why, when you remove it, your program stops working.

In the maze problem, a backtracking algorithm moves square by square. When from a square there is no possible path, this square must be marked as no path.

Comment: Actually there is one crucial difference in the two codes, although ultimately the bug is in his code. Check my answer.